# How do I remove certain characters before or after a certain number from a list of files in terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, batch-rename

Suppose there is a list of files with the following pattern:

```
ABC2011DEFG.txt
```

What command should I use to remove characters before or after the number in between while keeping the file extension?

Please note that the number of redundant characters is not fixed.

Comment: Can you clarify the *or* in "What command should I use to remove characters before or after the number in between while keeping the file extension?"? Are you asking for two different commands to remove either one or the other (hence for one to remove the sequence before the number and for one to remove the sequence after the number) or for a single command to remove both?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rename 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]*)[^0-9]*(\..*)/$1$2/' *
```

- `[^0-9]*` means anything but digits, any number of times
- `[0-9]*` means only digits, any number of times
- `(\..*)` means dot (`\.`), then anything (`.*`) - the extension
- `$1` is the content of what matched the first parentheses (the digits)
- `$2` is the content of what matched the second parentheses (the extension)

---

So if you have:

```
2012xyz.txt  ABC2011DEFG.txt  zyx2013.txt
```

you will get:

```
2011.txt  2012.txt  2013.txt
```

Comment: Indeed, I missed the part with keeping the extension - thanks. I updated the answer.

Comment: I *believe* that what is being asked is to remove *either* the characters before the number *or* the characters after the number, but it's not really clear. I can read it also the way you're reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/[^0-9]*//' *.txt # removes the first sequence of non-digits
rename -n 's/[^0-9]*\./\./' *.txt # removes the first sequence of non-digits followed by a dot
```

```
% rename -n 's/[^0-9]*//' *.txt
rename(ABC2011DEFG.txt, 2011DEFG.txt)
rename(HIJ2012KLMN.txt, 2012KLMN.txt)
rename(OPQ2013RSTU.txt, 2013RSTU.txt)
% rename -n 's/[^0-9]*\./\./' *.txt
rename(ABC2011DEFG.txt, ABC2011.txt)
rename(HIJ2012KLMN.txt, HIJ2012.txt)
rename(OPQ2013RSTU.txt, OPQ2013.txt)
```

If the files are going to be renamed as expected, remove the `-n` option.